# Mirror modifier problem for only one cube

Tags: mirror

182/5000
Hello . I try to make a low poly car with a background image, but when I try to apply a mirror modifier, it does not apply, and when I try another cube it goes. What is the problem? https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUOSf.jpg

Comment: question is not clear, can you explain more your setup and problem?

Comment: i wanna build a poly car. I add background image,apply loop cut , delete verticies and when i try to apply mirror it doesn t work

Comment: You could try to share your file to see the problem

Answer (score 1):

So from what I get from you question is that you are trying to model a low poly car with the mirror modifier activated. but you can't seem to apply it or add extra meshes?

**To be able to apply any modifier you need to be in object mode.**

1. So you would first create a cube and from front view in edit mode with "Control + R" create an edge loop in the middle
   [image]
2. after that you want to delete the first set of vertices on any side.[image]
3. And then apply the mirror modifier with "Clipping" checked 
   [image]

Then you can edit the mesh however you like and you have 2 ways of adding new meshes

- While in edit mode press "shift + a" to create a new mesh
- Go to object mode, press "shift + a" to create a new mesh and repeat
  steps 1 / 3 with the new model.

[image]